# Correct way to do Lagrange dual optimization PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-programming

I am trying to optimize a simple dual of a linear program using PyTorch. This is my code, but I keep getting an error with the backwards pass after the first loop:

```
c_t = torch.tensor(c).float()
A_t = torch.tensor(A).float()
b_t = torch.tensor(b).float()
x_t = torch.rand(n, 1, requires_grad=True)

def max_grad(grad):
    return -grad

_lagrange_multiplier = torch.rand(m, requires_grad=True)
_lagrange_multiplier.register_hook(max_grad) # because we maximize wrt lambda
lagrange_multiplier = torch.nn.functional.softplus(_lagrange_multiplier)

opt_weights = torch.optim.Adam([x_t], lr=0.1)
opt_lagrange = torch.optim.Adam([_lagrange_multiplier], lr=0.1)

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    opt_weights.zero_grad()
    opt_lagrange.zero_grad()

    objective = c_t.T @ x_t
    constraint = (A_t @ x_t).squeeze() - b_t
    lagrangian = objective + lagrange_multiplier.T @ constraint

    lagrangian.backward()

    opt_weights.step()
    opt_lagrange.step()
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
```

I thought that since I was zero_grading I could recall backwards?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I was not recomputing the variable lagrange_multiplier after I applied gradient updates to _ lagrange_multiplier. The corrected for loop is:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    opt_weights.zero_grad()
    opt_lagrange.zero_grad()

    objective = c_t.T @ x_t
    constraint = (A_t @ x_t).squeeze() - b_t
    lagrange_multiplier = torch.nn.functional.softplus(_lagrange_multiplier)
    lagrangian = objective + lagrange_multiplier.T @ constraint

    lagrangian.backward()

    opt_weights.step()
    opt_lagrange.step()
```